# Scripting.FileSystemObject seemed to not correctly DeleteFile in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I create a log file with day extension and I append text into this file. One month later, with the same name file (with same date) I need to delete the old file to restart with a new file. For this, I check the `DateCreated property`.
Everything is correct, the script see that the file is old, it remove it using `FileSystemObject.DeleteFile` and create a new file. But the new created file has the SAME `DateCreated value` as the old file! It seemed that the file system does not update the `DateCreated` value when it create a new file...
My script is an ASP class. I tried to use the `CreateTextFile`, the `OpenTextFile` with the force flag, I also tried to close the `FileSystemObject` and reopen it between the `DeleteFile` and the `OpenTextFile` without success.
How to completely erase the file from the filesystem ? Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "Tunneling" and is part of the filesystem (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=172190)). The solution is in the linked article, wait at least 15 seconds from delete of old file to creation of the new file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
For those who read this post, I modified my code to check the `DateModified` instead of `DateCreated`.